# Why am I getting Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. on setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this component:

```
// imports

export default class TabViewExample extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'first', title: 'Drop-Off', selected: true },
      { key: 'second', title: 'Pick up', selected: false },
    ],
  };

  handleIndexChange = index => this.setState({ index });

  handleStateIndexChange = () => { // FUNCTION WITH THE ERROR
    const { index } = this.state;
    this.setState(({ routes }) => ({
      routes: routes.map((route, idx) => ({
        ...route,
        selected: idx === index,
      })),
    }));
  };

  renderTabBar = props => {
    const { routes } = this.state;
    this.handleStateIndexChange(); // HERE I GET THE ERROR
    return (
      <View style={tabViewStyles.tabBar}>
        {props.navigationState.routes.map((route, i) => {
          return (
            <>
              <TouchableOpacity
                key={route.key}
                style={[
                  tabViewStyles[`tabStyle_${i}`],
                ]}
                onPress={() => this.setState({ index: i })}
              >
                <Text>
                  {route.title}
                </Text>
                // THE FUNCTION ATTEMPTS TO SHOW AN ELEMENT WHEN
                // THE INDEX OF A ROUTE IS selected true
                {routes[i].selected && (
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flex: 1,
                    }}
                  >
                    <View
                      style={{
                        transform: [{ rotateZ: '45deg' }],
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                )}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };

  renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: this.props.FirstRoute,
    second: this.props.SecondRoute,
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <TabView
        navigationState={this.state}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        renderTabBar={this.renderTabBar}
        onIndexChange={this.handleIndexChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Full error:

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

This is the function giving the error:

```
  handleStateIndexChange = () => { // FUNCTION WITH THE ERROR
    const { index } = this.state;
    this.setState(({ routes }) => ({
      routes: routes.map((route, idx) => ({
        ...route,
        selected: idx === index,
      })),
    }));
  };
```

All I need is to set the state of `selected` to `true` so I can toggle the visibility of a component.

Comment: You never setState in render directly in this call by calling a function in render that does that.

Comment: @AdeelImran so am I suppose to call it?

Comment: `setState` in render triggers another `render` which triggers another `setState` in the loop. It's an antipattern. Try to lift it up into lifecycle methods before `render`.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan If you see my code, I have this `this.handleStateIndexChange(); // HERE I GET THE ERROR` which is the function I am calling inside `renderTabBar` which is call on the render method. Also, if I use `setState` on `componentDidMount` I get the error that I should not use `setState` on a `componentDidMount` function.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `componentDidUpdate` not `componentDidMount`

Comment: you don't need `CDM` when you can just set your `state` initially in the `constructor`. You can use the `CDU` though if you put a safeguard `if` check to prevent additional `setState`calls for when the `state`  is not changed from the previous runs. It's an absolutely valid use case.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment above, you cannot call `setState` directly inside your render function.

I do not see any reason to keep the `selected` value in your state as it only depends on another value already in it, this information is redundant.

You should remove `selected` from all your objects in `routes` and change your JSX condition :

```
{routes[i].selected &&
```

To the following :

```
{i === this.state.index &&
```

To produce the same result.

You can now remove `handleStateIndexChange` from your code

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way React will batch state updates, if you need to set state based off previous state, you should do all the destructuring in the callback:

```
  handleStateIndexChange = () => {
    this.setState(({ index, routes }) => ({
      routes: routes.map((route, idx) => ({
        ...route,
        selected: idx === index,
      })),
    }));
  };
```

Also, as @Adeel mentions, you should not call `this.setState` from inside the `render` execution context. Move that call the `componentDidUpdate` instead.

Comment: According to @Adeel Imran comment I can not call setState on a render method which is what I am doing. If you see my code, I have this `this.handleStateIndexChange(); // HERE I GET THE ERROR` which is the function I am calling inside `renderTabBar` which is call on the render method. Also, if I use `setState` on `componentDidMount` I get the error that I should not use `setState` on a `componentDidMount` function.

Comment: Yes @Adeel is correct, calling setState inside render will cause infinite loops. You should be using `componentDidUpdate` to perform the state update.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `componentDidUpdate` not `componentDidMount `

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setState` in `render` is the actual reason for infinite rerender `loop`,
because setting `state` calls rerender, which calls another `setState` which calls another rerender etc.

So I would suggest to move the `setState` part into `componentDidUpdate` and control it there. Here is the [approximation](https://codesandbox.io/s/jlpvl92kw3) of what I mean with little changes to describe the point.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      {
        key: "first",
        title: "Drop-Off",
        selected: true
      },
      {
        key: "second",
        title: "Pick up",
        selected: false
      }
    ]
  };

  componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
    if (prevState.index !== this.state.index) {
      this.handleStateIndexChange();
    }
  }

  handleIndexChange = () => {
    const randomIndexBetweenZeroAndOne = (Math.random() * 100) % 2 | 0;

    this.setState({
      index: randomIndexBetweenZeroAndOne
    });
  };

  getMappedRoutes = (routes, index) =>
    routes.map((route, idx) => ({
      ...route,
      selected: idx === index
    }));

  handleStateIndexChange = () => {
    this.setState(({ routes, index }) => ({
      routes: this.getMappedRoutes(routes, index)
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { routes } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.handleIndexChange}>Change Index</button>
        {this.state.routes.map(JSON.stringify)}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```